# How to select date in DateRangePicker by clicking a span

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I am using dateRangePicker for calender plug in. I have a span "check in" which contains the current date. I want that when I click on that span the current date in the calender provided by dateRangePicker gets selected, but I don't know how to do it. Any kind of help is appriciatd. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I am using this one https://rawgit.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker/master/index.html

and here is my code

```
$('.datepicker1').dateRangePicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                separator : ' : ',
                startDate : today,
                showShortcuts : true,
                minDays: 2,
                getValue: function()
                {
                    console.log(today);
                    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
                    var day = today.getDate();

                    var output = today.getFullYear() + '/' +
                        (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
                        (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;
                    return output;
                },
                setValue: function(s)
                {
                    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
                    var day = today.getDate();

                    var output = today.getFullYear() + '/' +
                        (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
                        (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;
                    output = s;
                }
            })
            .bind('datepicker-change',function(event,obj){
                $(this).parent().parent().prevAll('.checkindate').html('<span>Check in</span><span>' + days[obj.date1.getDay()] + ', </span><span>' + dates[(obj.date1.getDate()-1)] + '</span><br><span>' + months[obj.date1.getMonth()] + ' ' + obj.date1.getFullYear() + '</span>');
                $(this).parent().parent().prevAll('.checkoutdate').html('<span>Check out</span><span>' + days[obj.date2.getDay()] +', </span><span>' + dates[(obj.date2.getDate()-1)] + '</span><br><span>' + months[obj.date2.getMonth()] + ' ' + obj.date2.getFullYear() + '</span>');
                $("#checkindate").val(obj.value.substr(0,obj.value.indexOf(":")));
                $("#checkoutdate").val(obj.value.substr(obj.value.indexOf(":")+1));
            });

$('.datepicker1').data('dateRangePicker').setDateRange('2014-06-03', "2014-06-04");
$('.datepicker1').click();
```

Comment: Please paste your code in question.. which dateRangePicker you are using? Also better if you provide a fiddle of your code.

Comment: @Pete No I'm using this [dateRangePicker](https://rawgit.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker/master/index.html)

Comment: Ok, if you look at the page you have linked to then the [download at github](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) has it's documentation which shows you can use `setValue (Function)` or `setDateRange` to set the date range, with an example of it's usage at the bottom, actually even the page you linked to shows that so why not rtfm?

Comment: @Pete I have tried both. When I used     setValue(Function) , no change occured. And when I used     setDateRange it gave me the following error  "setDateRange() is not a function"

Comment: so you would have had to place your click event after your initial call to your `$('.datepicker1').dateRangePicker()` - ie the code above, then used it like `$('.datepicker1').data('dateRangePicker').setDateRange('2013-11-20','2013-11-25')`

Comment: Example Usage: http://jsfiddle.net/3EZch/2/

Comment: Now it shows "data() is undefined"

Comment: can you update the code above with the new code and how you called it

Answer (score 0):

The Procedure for binding the event in span to select the current date in the JQuery Ui Datepicker

Use the `SetDate`  method of date picker to set date in span click.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnav1989/Fa8Xx/1892/